# _this2.setState is not a function error in react-native

Tags: react-native

I have this code for a drop down menu:

```
<Picker
    selectedValue= {() => {this.state.attendance}}
    onValueChange= {(att) => this.setState({attendance: att})}>
    <Picker.Item label="Present" value="present" />
    <Picker.Item label="Half Day" value="halfday" />
    <Picker.Item label="Informed Absent" value="in-absent" />
    <Picker.Item label="Uninformed Absent" value="un-absent" />
</Picker>
```

But I get an error, "_this2.setState is not a function" on running the app. I know how react-native doesn't auto bind, but from my research the arrow syntax ought to fix it. Anyone knows why this error is still being throw?

Comment: If you're using ES6 classes you can use [autobind-decorator](https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator) to do the binding for you. Simplifies things more than binding the context every time you call a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Closed the issue on github:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/9357